# Automatic conversion of decimal number

Tags: openoffice.org

I have this number 0.057287, if I write it in OOCalc, will be converted in 954.47.00. The only way to leave it as it was is to write '0.057287, but this last notation hide number from the charts. How can I turns off this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the format is set wrong for this column. Should be number and english format to show the number as you want it to show up.

Right click the cell and select 'Format Cell' (Libre office here but should be the same in OO)

Comment: Initially is setted to Standard number. As soon I insert a value into, it converts in time format.

Comment: you should be able to set it back to number again and keep that setting. If even that does not help you could try to specify the format yourself which should overrule auto formating.

Comment: I'm using dot as decimal separator, but my OO was configured in italian style, and use comma as deciamal separator. I've resolved. Thank u